# Truncar Valor em duas casas decimais em PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de truncar um valor em duas casas decimais no php, sem arredondar o valor.
Ex: 25,98/4 = 6,495.
Mas no PHP aparece 6,5
Estou usando o number_format:

```
 $valor_pedido = number_format($pedidoArray['valor_produto'] / ($totalComandasDiv + 1),2, '.', '');
```

Como Faço pra pegar o valor 6,49 ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$numero_decimal = 6.495;
$valor_pedido = floor($numero_decimal * 100) / 100;
```

O valor vai ser multiplicado por `100` e transformado em inteiro, tornando as duas casas decimais parte do inteiro. Depois é divido por `100` novamente para transformar os dois últimos dígitos nas casas decimais.

No seu código ficaria

```
$numero_decimal = $pedidoArray['valor_produto'] / ($totalComandasDiv + 1);
$valor_pedido = floor($numero_decimal * 100) / 100;
```

Demonstração: https://ideone.com/YSDlKR

Comment: O resultado deu 6,48.. Porem a divisão dá 6,495, ele arredondou para baixo, como manter apenas o 6,49 sem arrendondar o valor?

Comment: Quais os valores das suas variáveis no caso que deu 6,48? Olha um exemplo funcionando https://ideone.com/YSDlKR